# Как изменить стандартное расположение пользовательских папок у новых будущих пользователей?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Скажите пожалуйста, как в Windows 10 переместить папки: Документы, Загрузки, Видео, Изображения и т.д. из профиля пользователя в другой логический диск и как назначить пути на эти папки для новых
будущих профилей пользователей?

Comment: Свойства папки, вкладка «Расположение»

Comment: Да, я об этом знаю... Задача распространить эти настройки на всех пользователей, включая тех, чей профиль ещё не создан. Например, как переключение языка ввода, можно копировать параметры на новых пользователей...

Comment: Об этом стоило написать в заголовке, чтоб заметнее было

Comment: Спасибо, учту в новых вопросах. На мой вопрос может знаете ответ?)

Comment: Вот для новых пользователей к сожалению не знаю

Comment: Кажется вам нужно вот [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/storage/folder-redirection/deploy-folder-redirection)

Comment: Возможно придется через скрипт делать... Не могу найти решение через настройки...

Answer (score 0):

В свойствах перемещаемой папки поменяйте расположение
[image: Свойства папки]

Comment: Задача распространить эти настройки на всех пользователей, включая тех, чей профиль ещё не создан. Например, как переключение языка ввода, можно копировать параметры на новых пользователей...

Comment: Папку Users на этапе установки надо переносить.

Comment: Да, вы правы, вот только винда уже "глубоко" установлена, не хочу это делать. Ищу способ как в ней настроить... Спасибо.